# Access `expected` line from metadata

Tags: ruby, rspec, metadata

I want output line, which was failed during rspec comparasion inside example, but I don't know how to do it best.
For example I have test like this:

```
require 'rspec'

describe 'My behaviour' do
  it 'should do something' do
    test_string = 'test'
    expect(test_string).to eq('failed_test')
  end

  after :each do |example|
    puts example.metadata[:expect_line]
  end
end
```

And I want to outputed line in `after :each` be

```
"expect(test_string).to eq('failed_test')"
```

I know, I have acces to `example.metadata[:location]` which return something like `"./spec/test_spec.rb:4"` and I can parse it and extract line, but is there already something like I need hided in whole `example` structure?

Update:
I just understand. that `example.metadata[:location]` return not failed line, but actually line in whitch `it` started, so it have no use for me :(
So question still exist - how to get failed line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information isn't hidden anywhere in the example structure that I'm aware of.  RSpec's default output shows the line that failed:

```
Failures:

  1) My Description should fail
     Failure/Error: expect(1).to eq(2)

       expected: 2
            got: 1
```

If we look at how rspec itself gets this in [rspec/core/formatters/exception_presenter.rb](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/formatters/exception_presenter.rb) and [rspec/core/formatters/snippet_extractor.rb](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/formatters/snippet_extractor.rb), it appears that they go through the backtrace of the example exception to find the spec file and extract the line (similar to what you mentioned).  If there was an easier way to pull that out of the example, I would think RSpec itself would use that :)

Comment: Thanks, I use https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/formatters/exception_presenter.rb#L219 `find_failed_line` as a base, I wrote some pretty shitty-looking method to extracted needed line, but it works!